# added herf element not click-able

Tags: javascript, href, greasemonkey

I am trying to add a download element to the page. I click it using Greasemonkey.
The new div has been added to the page but the download window is not opening.

```
     var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
     iDiv.id = 'block';
     iDiv.className = 'block';
     document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0].appendChild(iDiv);
     iDiv.innerHTML = '<button class=button> <a href=' + link + ' target=_blank> </button>';
     document.getElementsByClassName('button') [0].click();
```

Comment: check the value of the **link** variable.

Answer (score 1):

`<a href=http://somesite.com target=_blank>` is invalid. You're missing quotes around the URL. 
Also, as @Springfield pointed out, you're not closing your `<a>` tag.

Solution :

```
iDiv.innerHTML = '<button class="button"> <a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">Link</a></button>';
```

which renders :

```
iDiv.innerHTML = '<button class="button"> <a href="http://somesite.com" target="_blank">Link</a></button>';
```

Comment: i was massing with it alot but even with the script i copy to my post the quotes where added to the href by them self. i did try the solution you posted but the same thing happen. the button is been added to the page but it looks like its still not been clicked on

Comment: Did you write anything inside your link? Because if you don't, it will be 0 pixel high, therefore impossible to click.

Comment: yes the link is pointing to a var with the url in it. the outpot in the page is: '
 
<div id="block" class="block"><button class="button"> <a href="https://example.com/images/public/int/8/2/8/7/886970767828.jpg">Link</a></button></div> '

Comment: I don't know, it should work, here is a very simple example : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/mwrEba

Comment: I did find out when adding a class to the <a> then the click the new class works. but because the link is to a link out side off the original site the button open the second site and not a download window. any fix for it or this is the limit of the html download attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Don't wanna be rude, but first questions first: Where does your anchor-tag end?

You open an a-tag, but its content as well as the end tag are both missing.

Comment: Nice catch, I have edited my answer according to your comment, which should have been a comment, not an answer :)